# Pasting images into Pages document very cumbersome - Inline vs automatic

Tags: pages, graphics

Pasting images into a Pages document is very cumbersome, requiring each individual image to be re-set and location to be adjusted manually to 'Move with Text' and 'Inline with Text':

[image]

Can image-pasting be made to default to that setting ?

Thanks muchly for anyone knowing of a (likely?) simple-yet-hidden solution.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that the image you want to replace is defined as a media place holder.  To do this click on the image that you want to replace so that it is active.  Now go to format at the top of your screen and choose "Advanced" from the "Format" drop down.  You should see the following bold text with a check mark in front of it "Define As Media Placeholder".  If it is not bold with a check mark in front of it click on it so that it is.
Once the image has been defined as a media placeholder right click on it and choose "Replace Image".  You will be given a choice of file paths to choose your new image which should then replace the original image and keep its formatting.  This only hitch is that you might be limited to choosing only those images which have been saved to your photo stream.

Comment: Thanks muchly for your reply, yogi - 
have tried... 
though am not attempting to 'replace' existing image, but simply keep pasting-adding new images 
Any additional image pasted into text-body is placed by defaulting to  'Text-wrap Automatic' causing pasted image placed at location other than intended- image pastes onto previous page or above the chapter/paragraph and needs setting 'Inline w Text' and re-placing manually - would love to have the default Object-placing to be 'Move w Text / Inline w Text' 

Well... thanks much for your reply 
good wishes 
peter

Answer (score 0):

I find that if I position the cursor within the text, and paste an image, then the Object Placement is anchored within the text stream, and defined as `Move With Text`. This is in Pages 10.0, which is current at time of writing.

The same is true if I drop an image directly into a paragraph of text, or use the menu item `Insert > Choose...` at the cursor position. So that's half the requirement.

There doesn't seem to be a way to set the default Text Wrap style, nor to select all images at once (short of Command-clicking them all) and then setting the wrap style.

However: one method that does seem to work:

1. Paste all the images into a blank, 'spare' Pages document. All the images need to fit on one page, so make the page size very big.
2. If the document contains nothing else, you can Select All the images, and then define their characteristics in one go.
3. You can then copy and paste each one into your target document, and their Text wrap style will be preserved.

From posts on other forums, e.g.: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7223123 , it does seem that this function does not 'formally' exist in Pages. The AppleScript Dictionary contains only one reference to text wrap, but in the context of tables, not images.

Ultimately, if this is a major impediment, you may be more productive in another application.